# Update records based on date on MySQL using joins

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, left-join, inner-join

I have all those tables above.

car_model_tbl

```
----------------------------- 
id  | car_model_name|status |
----------------------------- 
1   |   seria_1     |   1   |
----------------------------- 
2   |   golf_4      |   1   |
----------------------------- 
3   |   C_Class     |   1   |
----------------------------- 
4   |   golf_5      |   1   |
----------------------------- 
5   |   seria_2     |   0   |   
-----------------------------
```

car_manufacturer_tbl

```
------------------------- 
id  |car_manufactu_name |   
------------------------- 
1   |   bmw             |   
------------------------- 
2   |   volkswagen      |   
------------------------- 
3   |   mercedes        |       
-------------------------
```

car_service_tbl

```
--------------------------------- 
id  |   model_id| service_date  |   
--------------------------------- 
1   |   1       |   2018-03-10  |
--------------------------------- 
2   |   2       |   2018-02-10  |
--------------------------------- 
3   |   1       |   2018-01-10  |
---------------------------------
4   |   1       |   2017-12-10  |
--------------------------------- 
5   |   2       |   2017-12-10  |
--------------------------------- 
6   |   3       |   2018-02-10  |
--------------------------------- 
7   |   2       |   2018-01-10  |
--------------------------------- 
9   |   4       |   2018-03-10  |
--------------------------------- 
10  |   4       |   2018-02-10  |
--------------------------------- 
11  |   5       |   2018-02-10  |
---------------------------------
```

car_model_manufacturer_relation

```
-------------------------------------------------
id  | model_id  | manufactu_id| service_status  |
-------------------------------------------------
1   |   1       |   1         | 1               |
-------------------------------------------------
2   |   5       |   1         | 1               |
-------------------------------------------------
3   |   2       |   2         | 1               |
-------------------------------------------------
4   |   4       |   1         | 1               |
-------------------------------------------------
5   |   2       |   2         | 1               |
-------------------------------------------------
6   |   3       |   3         | 1               |
-------------------------------------------------
```

I need to update **car_model_manufacturer_relation.service_status    = '0'**
where **car_service_tbl.service_date < "2018-03-01"**.

In this case **car_model_manufacturer_relation.service_status** of models 2, 3 and 5 should be set to **'0'** because every **car_service_tbl.service_date** for these models is  smaller than "2018-03-01".

However, for models 1 and 4 **car_model_manufacturer_relation.service_status** should stay **'1'** because even that they have records smaller than "2018-03-01" they also have bigger dates ex. "2018-03-10".

I am trying to create a query for this but until now without success.

Comment: If you can show what query you have already, that is often appreciated by readers. It does not have to work, but it is useful because it will show your train of thought, and readers will have a better understanding of what specific think you need to learn. Would you do this now?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to nest a grouped query, to get the MAX date per model, and update from that.

```
update car_model_manufacturer_relation as cmmr, 
    (select model_id, max(service_date) as check_date 
        from car_service_tbl 
        group by model_id) as cst 
set cmmr.service_status = '0' 
where cmmr.model_id = cst.model_id 
and cst.check_date < "2018-03-01"
```

Where you're using more than one table and the table names include underscores, I try and alias the tables to make the code a little shorter and easier on the eye, hence the use of cmmr and cst as table aliases.

The MAX date has also been renamed for clarity as check_date.  You can of course name this anything you wish.

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please consider voting for it, and any other answers that have assisted you, in order that others may find the most appropriate solutions.

Answer (score 0):

With sub query:

```
UPDATE car_model_manufacturer_relation c
LEFT join (SELECT model_id, service_date FROM car_service_tbl ORDER BY service_date DESC LIMIT 1) as s  ON s.model_id = c.model_id
SET service_status=0
WHERE c.service_date < "2018-03-01"
```

Answer (score 0):

@tyro - be careful with your solution, as a LEFT JOIN would update the service status to 0 when there wasn't a service date within the car_service_tbl.  You would need to use a full join, rather than just the LEFT JOIN as you suggested in order to update the records correctly I feel.

Comment: By mistake you  put this as answer instead comment

Comment: Not a mistake - a rule of SO, that you can't comment until you reach 50 rep, unless you are commenting on your own post......  Thanks for the feedback though.  Once I reach the dizzying heights of 50 rep, I'll be sure to play by the rules!